# Effective way to modify an NSMutableArray inside a NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

Just learning and trying new things. I wonder if there is a better way to write this statement, or to modify an array inside of a dictionary. Looking for formatting, memory, and efficiency suggestions:

```
NSMutableArray *arrayCopy = [self.sortedTimeZonesDictionary objectForKey:currentTimeZone.sectionKey];
[arrayCopy addObject:currentTimeZone];
[self.sortedTimeZonesDictionary setObject:arrayCopy forKey:currentTimeZone.sectionKey];
```

Where my Dictionary is define as:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *sortedTimeZonesDictionary;
```

and is alloc'ed and init'ed with an array inside of each key.

Answer (score 2):

you could do only this:

```
[[self.sortedTimeZonesDictionary objectForKey:currentTimeZone.sectionKey] addObject:currentTimeZone];
```

Remember that you use pointers, so lets say that your NSMutableDictionary have a pointer to ArrayA, you only need to add an object to ArrayA.

What you are doing in your example is make `arrayCopy` point to the same memory address than your NSMutableDictionary object, and then add a new object in the array in that memory address. Last instruction won't have any effect since `arrayCopy` and `self.sortedTimeZonesDictionary[currentTimeZone.sectionKey]` points to the same address.